# Is there any way to use iron-session in EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, next.js

I'm trying to implement login through iron-session on a web page.

It works fine on localhost, but when I upload the code to EC2, the information is not saved in the cookie.
I think that req.session.save() did not work. Is there any solution?

I have no idea.
My code work at local perfectly.